# parsing inconsistent times with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I'm merging multiple excel files together using pandas with the code below. I have a problem converting the time in the 'time' column. Each spreadsheet is formatted differently and some have time as strings "0900" while some are formatted as time as 9:00. I need them to all be strings or all be time.

I tried the following code:

```
df_merge.assign(newtime = pd.to_datetime(df_merge.time).dt.time)
```

This converts the string "0900" values to 9:00, but it drops all the time values of 9:00 to NaN's... how can I deal with the difference in data type here?

```
df_merge = pd.DataFrame()
for f in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(path+"/"+f, header = None, skiprows = 1, 
                        names = ['sys_name','sys_no', 'date','time',
                                    'location','collected_by','date_set','date_comp',
                                    'smpl_type','total','fecal','cl_res','comment','lab_no'],
                        dtype = {'time':str})
        if len(df.columns) != 14:
            print(f, "is not formatted properly. It has", len(df.columns), "row(s) when it should have 14.")
        else:
            df_merge = df_merge.append(df, ignore_index=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

I also tried to convert the column to a string and parse using dateutil.parser:

```
df_merge['time'].apply(lambda x: parse(str(x)))
```

But for the rows formatted as "0900" I got 1325-02-22 00:00:00

Where the time is the year in this datetime..

Comment: what is the format in excel for "0900" is a str? and for 09:00 is format datetime or string?

Answer (score 0):

when i want to convert datetime to str i will use converters instead of dtypes:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path+"/"+f, header = None, skiprows = 1, 
                    names = ['sys_name','sys_no', 'date','time',
                   'location','collected_by','date_set','date_comp',
                   'smpl_type','total','fecal','cl_res','comment','lab_no'],
                    converters={'time': str})
```